# How to access a key in a multiple array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to output just the "status" key of the array below, but it's not working.

```
$array=array(
    [0] => array(
        [error] =>none 
        [response] => array( 
            [0] => array( 
                [status] => success
            )
        )
    ) 
    [1] =>  array(
        [error] =>failed 
        [response] => array( 
            [0] => array( 
                [status] => failed
            )
        )
    )
);

foreach ($array["status"] as $key => $value) {
    print '<br /> key: ' . $key . '  value: ' . $value;
}
```

My desired result should output status: success, status: failed

Comment: If you make things readable they may become understandable! Do you now see the `[0] and [1]` they are relevant as are all the other intemediary parts of the array

Comment: Do you want to print BOTH of the status's?

Comment: Yes, I want to print both status's.

Comment: Well you could do `echo $array[0]['response'][0]['status'];` and `echo $array[1]['response'][0]['status'];`

Comment: Did you create this array?

Comment: Not sure why you've an array in your "response" indexe tho...

Answer (score 1):

There you go :

```
foreach ($array as $k => $item) { //loop over all array
    foreach($item['response'] as $key => $value) { //loop over all "response" indexes
        echo "status item $k : {$value['status']} <br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are syntax errors in declaring array. You should not use [ ] for key, and you should use comma to separate array elements.

Here is the solution:

```
$array=array(
    '0' => array(
        'error' =>'none', 
        'response' => array( 
            0 => array( 
                'status' => 'success'
            )
        )
    ),
    '1' =>  array(
        'error' => 'failed', 
        'response' => array( 
            0 => array( 
                'status' => 'failed'
            )
        )
    )
);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {    
    echo "status item" . $key . " : " . $value['response'][0]['status'] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: The array was for information and the result of a `print_r()` most likely

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).